# Is it possible to use retrofit without model class?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

i have problem to use model class in retrofit lib. A backend side field name has changed.

Is it possible to get response without model class?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119905/retrofit-2-without-model-class

Comment: If your backend is not reliable, then Retrofit may be the wrong library. Just stick with OkHttp

Comment: Question doesn't make sens ... *Retrofit - **Type-safe** HTTP client for Android and Java by Square, Inc.*  ... *Is it possible to get response without model class?* **then what you wana get at the end?**

Comment: @Selvin OP probably means just get raw strings, not something that will need to be mapped to a user defined POJO class

Comment: ... or maybe some dictionaries(HashMap) ... but as you wrote - why Retrofit then? ... still *OP probably means just get raw strings* ... well without posting this in the question it's only blind guess

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can.

```
@POST("url")

 Call<JsonObject> register(@Query("name") String name,

                           @Query("password") String password);
```

Just write JsonArray or JsonObject according to your response instead of Model class.

Then, get data from JsonObject or JsonArray which you get in response as below

```
Call<JsonObject> call = application.getServiceLink().register();

call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                JsonObject object = response.body();
                //parse object 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your response ,i had illegal argument Exception,can please tell me how to define retrofit.It not working in  GET method

Comment: Thanks Mr.chetan ,issue fixed

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly possible using different return values. I assume that you currently use Gson to deserialize JSON responses, and they get converted to the actual class. However, you may choose to convert the returned response to `JsonElement` (or some more specific JSON class), in that case you will get a JSON item which you can manipulate as you wish to. Something like:

```
@GET("url")
Call<JsonElement> apiCall();
```

Comment: I don't think the converter is the issue. OP says a JSON field has changed, therefore invalidating the potential JSON annotations that Jackson or Gson would provide

Comment: Thanks Mr.Malcolm ,i Fixed the issue

Comment: @Vadivel You can upvote the answers that helped you, and don't forget to accept the one that helped you most.

Comment: I'm so sorry Mr.Malcolm, i'm not reach that much of reputation,

Comment: @Vadivel You have enough reputation now, you need only 15 points to do that.

Answer (score 3):

@Vadivel here it is the version of GET based on @chetan work:

```
@GET("http://your.api.url")
Call<JsonObject> getGenericJSON();

Call<JsonObject> call = api.getGenericJSON();
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.body().toString());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in getGenericJson:" + response.code() + " " + response.message());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get response without model class

If I get you right - sure. You do not have to make response JSON auto-converted. You can do this easily by hand if needed, by retrieving raw response. Once you got that you can do whatever you need.

Comment: @Vadivel, if you fixed this issue, could you give some answers corresponding to your problems and how you fixed it. I am facing same issue like you. Thanks.

Comment: I just refer first  answer post of this question. just use  instead of Call<JsonObject>  to Call<JsonElement>

Comment: @Vadivel,it is ok now .Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply "rename" field on your side using

```
@SerializedName("newFieldName")
SomeClass oldField;
```