# How to call Static Google Map using retrofit?

Tags: android, google-maps, retrofit2, pojo

I am trying to make an `HTTP GET` API call to properly append `Static Google Map` to an `image view`.

The below tutorial has shown how to do it using the `http client method`.

http://www.journaldev.com/10392/android-google-static-maps-example-tutorial

But when using the `retrofit` I need a `pojo` class right?

How do I make `pojo` for a `response` like in the below link.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%22%20+lati%20+%20%22,%22%20+%20longi%20+%20%22&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false%22;%20Bitmap%20bmp%20=%20null;

Or is there a way to do this without `pojo` using `retrofit`.

The response we get after we make the call is a bitmap according to the following voted post.

[How to display static google map on android imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324004/how-to-display-static-google-map-on-android-imageview)

Comment: You only need a POJO when using a Converter like the Gson one. If you only want to fetch HTTP, you can use Okhttp

Comment: but i would like to make this call using retrofit can i make it without a pojo if so how ?

Comment: Are you getting JSON? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503343/is-it-possible-to-use-retrofit-without-model-class  Or a string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617770/how-to-get-response-as-string-using-retrofit-without-using-gson-or-any-other-lib

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|13.0827,80.2707&zoom=13&size=400x400&sensor=true...this is the url the response is an image. please read my question i completely explained my problem

Comment: Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(myDataList.get(position).getImage())
                    .into(holder.imageThumb);
 I am using Glide to show static Google image
You can use Picasso or any other image loading library

Comment: QAMAR please post it as an answer the code part where to place the url key etc

Comment: did you come up with a solution? It would be awesome to see the complete result here =)