# Retrofit 2 response without model

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, rx-java2

There are only following questions asked for this issue [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119905/retrofit-2-without-model-class), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973633/retrofit-2-get-json-from-response-body)
but they don't solve my question.

## Question:

Suppose my api at `http://www.example.com/getSomething` will give `{"Status":"False"}`.

```
// desired
public Apiinter{
  @GET("http://www.example.com/getSomething")
  Observable<Boolean> getSomething();
}
```

i want something like `Observale<Boolean>` as returned , without making any extra **POJO** on the way, how to achieve that

**My Try:**

i can use a **POJO/model** (but i don't want to) , i can return `JSONObject` or `JSONElement` , but that will make not make `Observable<Boolean>` as returned value

Comment: my be try custom convertors. But why not POJO?

Comment: this is only 1 api example i have 20+ api's with only 1 variable returning as response in json , so imagine making that many pojo's

Comment: it's ill logical you are trying to pass primitive data type only. you also need to pass key which have value to parse

Comment: exactly i know , i'm just asking for possibilities to achieve or convert it into the desired Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth be told, I'd still rather go with 20+ POJOs than this but you might consider adding your custom JsonDeserializer (assuming you will use GSON for parsing your API results). The deserializer i can think of looks something along these lines:

```
   private static class BooleanDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
        @Override
        public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
            Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = obj.entrySet();
            return ((JsonElement)entrySet.toArray()[0]).getAsBoolean();
        }
    }
```

And setting up your Gson like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, new BooleanDeserializer()).create();
```

And your RestAdapter:

```
final RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                ...
                .setConverter(gson);
```

You's probably want to mess around with it a little bit and of course, this saves you work only to a degree. I don't know how your APIs differ but this should be useful for cases where you may have different API structures but only one useful value.

Comment: you're welcome! i forgot to mention that you probably want to return Observable<Boolean> instead of just Boolean (I didn't want to dig into that since I'm not really proficient in rx-java) but I'm sure you'll manage.